# disallow portion of input text to be cleared using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, regex

I have a textbox where text has to entered in particular format `FIXEDPORTION TEXTTOBEKEYED`.
How do i disallow the FIXEDPORTION to be cleared using jquery?

Comment: Is there any character separating the two parts? A character that is not allowed more than once in the input?

Comment: The fixed part looks like this USA-MER for example. The two part is separated by a space but the second part can also contain space.

Comment: why can't you have two textboxes..one for fixedportion and the other one normal.You can always concatenate the value while processing

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you're looking for:

Your example data:

```
FIXEDPORTION TEXTTOBE KEYED
```

This regex:

```
^[^\s]+
```

matches:

```
`FIXEDPORTION`
```

Example:

http://regex101.com/r/eZ8hK8

So in regex/javascript:

```
var txt = "FIXEDPORTION TEXTTOBE KEYED";

var fixedInput = txt.match(/^[^\s]+/);

print(fixedInput);
```

Output:

```
FIXEDPORTION
```

Comment: I mean the fixed portion shouldn't be cleared while other portion can be cleared.

Comment: So when the text is cleared using backspace or anything the fixed portion wont be removed??

Comment: I'm not understanding what you meant by the word "cleared".  cleared can mean, {cleared out of the way/removed} or it can mean {clear/free from manipulation}..  and many other meanings actually..

Comment: ohhh.. do you mean "deleted" using the backspace key? or delete key?

Comment: yes backspace. I dont want the fixed portion to be removed as it will be inserted based on the value from other input control. other portion is keyed in by user which can be removed by user.

Comment: The scenario is something like this. When the page is loaded the input field will contain the fixed portion. User cannot removed/cleared the fixed portion/text originally present in the texbox. user can type/key more text in the input field and also clear/remove all the text other than the fixed portion.

Comment: Ahhh ok, well there are many different solutions to this. Is the fixed portion always the same text?  if so, fixed text could just be a background image for the input textbox element.  or if not, still you could have label containing the fixed portion, and next to it the input box, but then with css remove background and border from the input box so it appears invisible, and you would wrap both label and input with a div that has a background image that looks like a text box..  This is not really a regex question at all.. it is more just html/css question.

Comment: You could even ablolute position a label/text in the text box.. Definitely your problem should be accomplished with just a little html styling (CSS).. If you don't know how to accomplish this with html/css, then you should re-tag your question to CSS & HTML, and just post the relevant html and css code of the input box and the fixed portion.  :)

Comment: Yes i have tried that using a span and textbox with padding and left position adjustment .since i am using bootstrap i finding it difficult to achieve this. Also i have seen many jquery masking where this has been achieve and guess without css styling

Comment: ok, with jquery, it probably could be done.., but quite complicated compared to just html/css because realize you're asking to not only detect on every key/text input to make sure you haven't backspace to a given length, but also regex remove the fixed text on submit (that probly should be in an input box to begin with),  You're going to need to make your first attempt at this yourself, and then re-post your question with your attempt and what exactly you're have problems with.  no one is going to completely write your code for you without you tryign what you can first.  good luck!  :)